# Using Decimal datatype in Excel Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking for a way to use the Decimal datatype in an Excel worksheet.  I am storing routing information as a number.  Routings could consist of 10 moves to 50 different locations.  This works fine in VBA by using the decimal data type, but I cannot get Excel to accept these numbers once it is passed from VBA.

It seems to default the data type to Double which does not hold enough accuracy for my application.  Also, a string representation of a number will not suffice since I am backing out of the number in the worksheet.

---

Here is what I have so far for generating the Route#:

```
'generate route# for each row
For i = intFirstRow To intLastRow
    'initiate route#
    decRoute = CDec(dblInitialRoute)
    For j = 1 To 7
        'only assign if labor
        If arrLabor(i, j, 1) <> 0 And arrLabor(i, j, 1) <> "" Then
            'some stations could lead to multiple machines
            If arrLabor(i, j, 2) = 1 Then
                sglRandom = Rnd()
                If sglRandom < 0.8 Then
                    intValue = 1
                Else
                    intValue = 3
                End If
                decRoute = decRoute + intValue * (50 ^ ((decRoute - Int(decRoute)) * 100)) - 0.01
            ElseIf arrLabor(i, j, 2) = 10 Then
                sglRandom = Rnd()
                intValue = Int((sglRandom * 1000) / (1000 / 20)) + 10
                Debug.Print intValue
                decRoute = decRoute + intValue * (50 ^ ((decRoute - Int(decRoute)) * 100)) - 0.01
            Else
                intValue = arrLabor(i, j, 2)
                decRoute = decRoute + intValue * (50 ^ ((decRoute - Int(decRoute)) * 100)) - 0.01
            End If
        End If
        'exception
        If arrLabor(i, j, 1) = "" And j = 2 Then
            intValue = 44
            decRoute = decRoute + intValue * (50 ^ ((decRoute - Int(decRoute)) * 100)) - 0.01
        End If
    Next
    'write route#
    Debug.Print CDec(Int(decRoute) + dblInitialRoute)
    wsActive.Cells(i, intRouteCol).Value = CDec(Int(decRoute) + dblInitialRoute)
Next
```

Comment: Which version of Excel?  Also what about using the Double data type?

Comment: Excel 2013...  Double is rounding off some of my numbers.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting.  The purpose of a double is to "Use the Double data type to store precision floating point numbers"  Try Decimal or Currency http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2

Comment: My problem is the excel worksheet is not accepting values passed as Decimal

Comment: What are your variables' types?

Comment: Routing information sounds like a number, but it is a reference isn't it? Each number means something in a sequence. I think better to use a Routing reference "number" as a String. Then to decipher the routing number in reverse, you'd pick off the referencing information then you could use: substring(), mid(), left(), or right(). Creating a routing number, try using a reference map that you create and create the number in sequences and "String" it together as an informational sequence of characters (in your case, numbers).

Comment: Also I noticed a Rand(), which isn't guaranteed to be random at all. Not knowing why your code is the way it is, or trying to guess, have you thought of "collisions"? And what you'd do with collisions? Then a Hash Map comes to mind. As you've laid out your function on display, it really doesn't lend a reason for it's functionality other than a way to produce a random number based on a couple caveats. Since I don't know what your design is for, at all, I can only guess and offer advice which might be 100% inaccurate. Offer some more details (edit) and maybe someone will see a better way.

Comment: I am generating routing information for piece parts in a fab shop to feed my simulation model...  The routing number is for me to store which operations are performed on each part and the sequence.  The rand() is for a probability bc I don't have complete routing information so I'm using a distribution.  Don't see how this helps whether Excel can use Decimal datatypes within the worksheet..... this is not a VBA question.  The VBA was added for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell numeric type is **double precision floating point** capable of holding upto 15 digits of precision.

> Excel stores numbers differently that you may have them formatted display on the worksheet. Under normal circumstances, Excel stores numeric values as "Double Precision Floating Point" numbers, or "Doubles" for short. These are 8-byte variables that can store numbers accurate to approximately 15 decimal places. You may have only two decimal places displayed on the worksheet, but the underlying value has the full 15 decimal places.
>
> The second problem arises from the fact that a computer, any computer, cannot store most fractional numbers with total accuracy. Computers, in general, use the IEEE (Institute Of Electrical And Electronic Engineers) standard for floating point numbers. This standard provides a way to store fractional numbers in the limited space of an 8-byte number. Of course, for most numbers, some approximation must be made.

<sup>[Rounding and Precision in Excel - CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rounding.htm)</sup>

It seems that you are trying to hold more precision that what is designed for.  You can store more digits by making the number bigger say a factor of 1x10^15.  It will store the extra information for you but it may not work with the machine you have.

Comment: Sounds like Excel won't accept the Decimal data type which keeps the accuracy to 28 digits?